# Laravel 4 installation error on my VPS - "class PDO not found"

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I'm installing my app on my VPS.  composer create-project runs through everything gets just past "Generating autoload files" and then throws the following error:

{"error":{"type":"Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'PDO' not found","file":"/home/mysite/myapp/app/config/database.php","line":16}}Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
  Error Output:

Need your help!

Comment: Make sure you enable the pdo extension on your php.ini file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your vps is CentOS: `yum install php-pdo`
or alternatively: `pecl install pdo`

Comment: I use php54 and php54-pdo is installed but still i get the error when I wanted to open phpmyadmin